# Application android Hybrid

Tags: android, web-frameworks, ip-geolocation

I have to develop an android application that use geolocation, and I am confused to choose between web framework mobile and native Android application, and if I must to choose a web frawework which one do you recommend to me?

Comment: Native is the best. Nothing can replace the flexibility the native android sdk can provide. try using the native sdk itself..just my piece of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are many kinds of framework : like JQuery mobile , Phonegap , titanium , Windev for mobilephones

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the firs part of your question, I'd say this depends on a couple of factors:

1.) Previous experience: Do you already possess experience working with HTML/CSS + JQuery or do you possess experience working with Java? If your answer is yes to the first part: go for web framework development. If your answer is yes to the second part (Java): go for native app development, trust me, it's really easy to pick up if you have already worked with Java before and possess basic knowledge about inheritance and working with packages etc., also, start with the tutorials on developer.android.com If your answer is no to both parts of that question then I'd suggest you go with native app development since picking up Java is relatively easier compared to HTML/CSS+Javascript, in my opinion. If your answer is yes to both parts of the question (i.e you've worked with both Java and HTML/CSS+JS) then look at point 2.

2.) Personal Preference: Clearly, you don't have one right now so just go with what feels easier.

3.) **For a geolocation app** I'd say native app development is easier, I've been working on a geolocation based app for a while now and I felt that using the Google Maps API was pretty easy and you'll also find significant amounts of help from stackoverflow since everyone and their mothers have tried to make a geolocation-based app. I found the answers to most of my problems here on SO.

If you need more suggestions on this matter don't hesitate from asking!